# SQL Formatting a field

Tags: sql, sqlite, formatting

In my DB, I have a column called `telephone number`.
Most of the numbers are ###-###-#### some of them are ###########.  How can I run a query to format all numbers to look the same?

I'd prefer:

```
###-###-#####
```

Comment: u can use case statement by using length function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a scripting langauge for something like this. In PHP:

```
$string = "1234567890";
$formatted_string = substr($string,0,3)."-".substr($string,3,3)."-".substr($string,6,4);
```

Answer (score 1):

I sure hope you are dealing with U.S. (assumed from your example) phone numbers only. Once you start going international, things get tough. I also hope the variations are only the two you said... SQL isn't very good at this, but here goes.

**EDIT** A SQLite query, as requested. I used the SQLite documentation, specifically core functions http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html and select statements http://sqlite.org/lang_select.html.

```
select SUBSTR(Phone, 1, 3) + '-' +
         SUBSTR(PHONE, 4, 3) + '-' + 
         SUBSTR(PHONE, 7, 4)
from (
    select REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Phone, '-', ''), '(', ''), ')', ''), ' ', '') Phone
    from source
) xx
```

My original queries work in MS SQL.

```
select SUBSTRING(Phone, 1, 3) + '-' + 
         SUBSTRING(PHONE, 4, 3) + '-' + 
         SUBSTRING(PHONE, 7, 4)
from source
where CHARINDEX(Phone, '-') = 0
```

You might consider cleaning up all the phone numbers first. EG:

```
select SUBSTRING(Phone, 1, 3) + '-' +
         SUBSTRING(PHONE, 4, 3) + '-' + 
         SUBSTRING(PHONE, 7, 4)
from (
    select REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Phone, '-', ''), '(', ''), ')', ''), ' ', '') Phone
    from source
) xx
```

Phone numbers can get ridiculously complex. For example, I missed periods in that clean up. I strongly recommend cleaning them up in some other code than T-SQL.

Comment: All numbers are USA, Puerto Rico.

Comment: SQLite doesn't have SUBSTRING or CHARINDEX. It does have SUBSTR but not sure what CHARINDEX is

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice the SQLite requirement. CHARINDEX is simply a function to locate a character in a string if you imagine each position of the string numbered from 1 to length. I haven't found a similar function in SQLite.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LENGTH(telephone_number)=10
            THEN Do Something
            ELSE DEfault
       END
FROM YOURTABLE;


----------
```

PS: This is a arbitrary solution.

Comment: I would use CONCAT,SUBSTR functions in the place of "Do Something"